# Need help getting excel to pull values from a chart using name and date

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have an excel sheet that reps daily numbers into. I am trying to create a second chart that can show the daily totals based on the date entered into a selection cell.

Attached a picture for a reference. In this example, when the date 5/22/2020 is entered into D10, I would like E12 = 10, E13 = 8, F12=650.00 and F13 = 850.00.

I tried using vlookup but cant seem to find a method for searching by two criteria (name and date).

Does anyone have any suggestions about getting something like this work work ?

I would appreciate any help that could be provided. '

[image: Sample of Excel File]

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS:

Put this in E12 and copy over and down:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,$E:$E,$D$10,$D:$D,$D12)
```

Comment: Tried entering that formula and got a return of zero in the Rep1 Contacts Field.After getting an error message saying there are one or ore circular references.